# Devise / Rails - Adding some custom code to the new sessions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

What I need to do is having the login work for either a username or an email (for legacy reasons).

How would I go about doing this?  I can override the default session controller but I think there is probably a better way.

```
id: 1, email: racro1@cable.net, username: racro1, password: ****
```

so

```
user: racro1
pass: racro1pw
```

and

```
user: racro1@cable.net
pass: racro1pw
```

would both log in the racro1 user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [How To: Allow users to sign_in using their username or email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address) in the Devise wiki.

Comment: I honestly looked there and didn't see it.  Thanks!